# Open default Mail Client in "Web@Work" for Android

Tags: javascript, html

I have problems with a "Give Feedback" feature in a Web-Browser für Android.
The Browser is called "Web@Work" from MobileIron
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobileiron

I'm using a "MailTo" Link to open the default mail-client.

```
<a href="mailto:dummymail@gmail.net">Give Feedback</a>
```

On Chrome/Firefox/IE/Safari/etc. it works without problems. 
The user gets asked which app he wants to use to send an email.

On the "Web@Work" for Android i get the following:

[Web@Work MailTo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qgK4.png)

It tries to load the link in the Browser instead of asking for an E-Mail-Client.
The message is german for: "The URI-Scheme is not supported"

Has anyone encountered this problem before?

Comment: So maybe it's browser issue? I would not use app that has 2.3 rating

Comment: Not using the app is sadly not an option for me :(
Our client has to use it for every company owned android phone.